# Cannot create a model segue by dragging in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I am new for Xcode , I am trying to build my first easy project by following this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9bsZvHuQYI

However , between 2:23 to 2:25 , the way he try to create a segue from home to another view controller is not working , I try to drag by holding ctrl and left mouse to another view controller there is nothing response (usually it will appear a blue window to tell you can link with it) , is that cause by the new version of Xcode?

I'm appreciate for any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may have to do with the version of your editor, but you can always create a segue that's not associated with a button click or a table row click by control dragging from the View Controller icon on the controller. I had trouble making a screenshot so please excuse my drawn in mouse.

[image]

Comment: actually I tried that before , by using my track pad , it doesn't work at all , however after I finish my dinner and come back again , read your writing , then I grab a mouse and do it without using trackpad it works , I think probably there is some unknown bug there.